# Can bounty description use MathJax and MarkDown?

Tags: support, mathjax, bounty, markdown

When offering a [bounty](/questions/tagged/bounty), it is possible to add a custom message. Does this message has to be plain text? Or can we use similar formatting as in the posts? (I.e., MathJax for mathematics, [Markdown](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for formatting. Or perhaps at least the limited version of MarkDown, which is [used in comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).)

---

P.S.

I am aware that if it is possible, I could simply go through questions which are [currently featured](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=featured) or which were [featured in the past](https://twitter.com/StackMath). Perhaps if I am patient enough, I will find a question where bounty description has MathJax/Markdown.

Another possibility would be to find some bounty-worthy question and then try whether MathJax/Markdown in the bounty description will be displayed.

Despite the fact that this could be verified experimentally without much effort, I think it is good to have documented here on meta whether this is possible or not. (I guess this may be useful for other users who have the same question.)

Comment: Wasn't there an issue a month or so ago where the mathjax in the bounty description rendered in a really botched way? Edit: [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23213/is-it-possible-to-edit-bounty-messages).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to SE developer [Geoff Dalgas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120346):

> Bounty notices will support our Markdown mini format, using the same format as we allow for comments.  The following will be allowed:
>
> ```
> _italic_ and **bold** text,
> inline `code in backticks`,
> and [basic links](http://example.com).
> ```
>
> And just like in comments: line breaks [are not rendered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124016/line-breaks-paragraphs-for-bounty-text).

MathJax is a separate issue: it runs on the entire page, so it will be rendered anywhere. However, there is no preview when entering it.